# How do i make background blur when i open my app?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have to make the background (of desktop) blur when i open my app.how do i do this please help me out with hints or links..

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a screenshot.
2. Apply some blurring to the screenshot bitmap (e.g. Gaussian).
3. Display a fullscreen window with processed screenshot as content.
4. Show your window on top of the fullscreen window.

The details depend on the OS and the technology you are working with.

If *dimming* instead of *blurring* is OK, you can just show a black fullscreen rectangle with alpha less than one (as suggested in the answer by Seçkin).

Though I must add that as a user I would resent an application doing that to me. Unless it's a nuclear missile launch control application (or something with similarly drastic consequences of a user mistake), I'll just uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would create a semi-transparent rectangle which spans entire screen to achieve this effect. It is similar to see behind blurry glasses: World is not blurred, just glasses make it perceived blurry.

Comment: but i am not suppose to implement this i.e create a window and blur it.Can u please help me with some other idea......

Comment: and what are you supposed to do? who asked you not to do that?